# Mysterious .dat0000.000 files are flooding my apps documents folder

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

One of my apps has been on the app store for quite some time now and it has proven to be very reliable and stable.

Today I received an email from a user who reported that in his company, several installations of the app had started to gradually take up huge amounts of disk space, on one device as much as 5 GB!! Where usually, even with user data generated over the course of years, the app won't go beyond 10 MB.

Upon closer examination using iPhone Explorer, the client found a large number of files in my apps document folder, with sizes varying between 20 and 35 MB each to be responsible.

Those files are named, for example: .dat0065.01f or .dat009c.014 and they don't belong there. My app isn't (deliberately) writing these, I've never heard of them before, I have never seen similar files in the document folder of my app on my devices.

So, where are they coming from?

Could this be some (3rd party) framework going wild? I'm using dropbox, testflight, GDataXML.

Does the naming scheme ring a bell for you?

And how do I even start debugging this, when it doesn't occur on my devices?

Any help on this would be much appreciated!!

Comment: have you or this user looked at the contents of the file? how does the user know it's your app responsible for them? could something else be dumping you app folder?

Comment: I second @Marc.  I would make certain this is indeed your app before you spend any time investigating (if you haven't already done so).  It has also been said that iPhone Explorer is unstable and potentially dangerous (take that to mean whatever you wish).  Do any other apps report these files as well in iPhone Explorer, or just yours?  Are your users' devices jailbroken?

Comment: Smells like some sort of log file, maybe TestFlight as Jeremy suggests.

Comment: I have asked the user to send me a couple of these files for further investigation. I also asked for more info about the affected devices (jailbreak yes/no). Maybe this will shed some light on the matter. As for testflight... I know it keeps logs, but I've never observed them to grow that large, let alone to remain on the device after transmission. And I'd expect other users to report similar problems too. But as a matter of fact, tesflight was my first shot too. However Google didn't reveal any connections of bloated log files or files with similar names to testflight...

Comment: I am vaguely recalling that some database packages use files like that for a commit journal, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TestFlight framework you mentioned allows tracking of how beta testers are using the application.  After perusing their documentation, I noticed a section on logging.  TestFlight has the ability to log data to a file and will then send that data to their servers on Session End events.  This capability is turned **ON** by default.

This is a red flag.  I would start there.

Reference: [TestFlight SDK Documentation](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/doc/1.0/)

Comment: Good call. While I initially guessed the same, I dumped the idea because of hundreds of other users where the framework didn't fail this way. However the files I received from the client today leave no doubt - they contain json log data clearly related to testflight. Guess I'll have to ask them why it is possible for their logs to build up 5 GB when usually one log is a few kb at the most...